# How to marshall a complex HashMap structure

Tags: spring, jaxb, jersey

i have this class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="maps")
class MyClass{
 private Map<Date, Map<String,AnotherClass>> struct=new 
 HashMap<Date,Map<String,AnotherClass>>();
 //getters setters
}
@XmlRootElement(name="another")
class AnotherClass{
   //fields + methods
}
```

I want to implement an Adapter for MyClass so that i can marshall a List to XML.
Any Suggestion on how i can implement marshall and unmarshall methods of the Adapter?
Thx.

Comment: I found a way to do it for Map<Date, AnotherClass> but how can i do it more dynamically by a kind of recursive call then the second type is also a Map : Map<Date,Map<String,AnotherClass>> ?